# NativeScript-Vue: How to install BottomNavigation component

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue, nativescript-plugin, android-bottomnavigationview

How can I install the BottomNavigation component which is used in the playground here?

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=Evc8t6&v=4

I am using NativeScript 8 and it looks like the latest Version of NativeScript do not support this feature anymore. (I use NativeScript 8.0)

Is there a third party plugin or something else which brings this feature back?

**Update:**
Here es the reason why it is not there anymore and where you can find it:
https://blog.nativescript.org/nativescript-8-announcement/#important-note-about-bottomnavigation-and-tabs

Unfortunately the icon's do not work for me.

For example this is not loading:

```
<Image src="font://&#xf00e;" class="fas"></Image>
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have similar issue and found your topic, thanks!

For the image, try:

`<Image src.decode="font://&#xf00e;" class="fas"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Things like Bottom Navigation and so on is not in Nativescript 8 anymore. They are provided by the community.

here you can find all the community driven components:
[nativescript-community](https://nativescript-community.github.io/)

But I realised that not all components work as expected, eg:
there are two bottom navigation bars, one works and one just doesn't, the whole project crashes instead

For my Nativescript 8 project I use this one:
[Material Bottom navigation bar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nativescript-community/ui-material-bottomnavigationbar)